HTTP connection closed unexpectedly issue in akka-stream application
In my akka-streams(scala) application, I am using google pubsub as the source, querying from a BigQuery table and then publishing an outcome to a kafka topic and later acknowledging the pubsub
message. But I am intermittently facing this issue.
Runtime exception encountered: [{}], stopping stream 
akka.http.impl.engine.client.OutgoingConnectionBlueprint$UnexpectedConnectionClosureException: The http server closed the connection unexpectedly before delivering responses for 1 outstanding requests
    at akka.http.impl.engine.client.OutgoingConnectionBlueprint$.$anonfun$apply$7(OutgoingConnectionBlueprint.scala:123)
    at akka.http.impl.engine.client.OutgoingConnectionBlueprint$.$anonfun$apply$7$adapted(OutgoingConnectionBlueprint.scala:123)
    at akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$One2OneBidi$$anon$1$$anon$4.onUpstreamFinish(One2OneBidiFlow.scala:97)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:536)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:400)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:650)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:521)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:625)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:800)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$shortCircuitBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:787)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:819)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:716)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:579)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:547)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
akka.http.impl.engine.client.OutgoingConnectionBlueprint$UnexpectedConnectionClosureException: The http server closed the connection unexpectedly before delivering responses for 1 outstanding requests
    at akka.http.impl.engine.client.OutgoingConnectionBlueprint$.$anonfun$apply$7(OutgoingConnectionBlueprint.scala:123)
    at akka.http.impl.engine.client.OutgoingConnectionBlueprint$.$anonfun$apply$7$adapted(OutgoingConnectionBlueprint.scala:123)
    at akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$One2OneBidi$$anon$1$$anon$4.onUpstreamFinish(One2OneBidiFlow.scala:97)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:536)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:400)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:650)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:521)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:625)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:800)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$shortCircuitBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:787)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:819)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:716)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:579)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:547)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)


I am using below:
for pubsub source: akka.stream.alpakka.googlecloud.pubsub.scaladsl.GooglePubSub
for bigquery source: akka.stream.alpakka.googlecloud.bigquery.scaladsl.BigQuery
for bigquery response serialization: defined custom akka.stream.alpakka.googlecloud.bigquery.scaladsl.spray.BigQueryRootJsonFormat
for kafka publish sink: akka.kafka.scaladsl.SendProducer
I have tried setting below configs:
BigQuery request timeout: 3minutes

akka.kafka.producer {
  discovery-method = akka.discovery
  topic = "mytopic"
  service-name = ""
  resolve-timeout = 3 seconds
  parallelism = 10000
  close-timeout = 60s
  close-on-producer-stop = true
  use-dispatcher = "akka.kafka.default-dispatcher"
  eos-commit-interval = 100ms
  kafka-clients {
    //my kafka-client configs
  }
}

akka.http{
    idle-timeout = 180s
}

akka.http.host-connection-pool.max-open-requests = 256
akka {
  http {
    client {
      # Timeout for the entire request
      request-timeout = 180s
      # Timeout for the idle connection
      idle-timeout = 180s
      # Timeout for connecting to the server
      connecting-timeout = 180s
    }
  }
}

I have tried setting the idle-timeout for bigquery explicitely, but that doesn't cause this issue, rather throws a bigquery idle-timeout. None of the above configs seem to fix this issue.
I am new to akka-http, would really appreciate any help/suggestions on this.

According to the error message, it's the server that's closing the connection, so nothing that you change in your Akka HTTP settings is going to have any impact because that only changes the client, your settings can't affect what the server does. First thing you need to work out is whether it's Google PubSub or BigQuery that's closing the connection (you have two HTTP connections involved in your stream here, one to Google PubSub, one to BigQuery). It's possible that it's Google PubSub.
